# TextBox_append_text_with_encoding() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I installed `mysql workbench` from Ubuntu Software Center and it was correctly installed , but when I opened it I saw this error:

```
TextBox_append_text_with_encoding() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

then the server stopped.

Comment: Some solutions were mentioned here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1573624. I cannot test, but you obviously can.

Comment: Then bug reports mentions ^the above question